# class_weight='auto' for model.fit_generator keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have a highly unbalanced dataset and I want to use the `class_weight = 'auto'` in the `model.fit_generator`. However, when I do that I see that my model does not learn: `training_acc = 0.65` and `val_acc = 0.64` starting from epoch 1 up to 50. 
If I set the `class_weight = 'None'` then the model starts learning: `training_acc = 0.92 and val_acc = 0.88 at epoch 50`.

Did anyone else face this problem? Do I have to define a dictionary to my class weights manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `model.fit_generator` in keras you can use `train_generator.classes` for the proper class names for your weighting

Then you simple create a dictionary mapping your classes., e.g.

```python
class_weights = {'wolf':30 , 'fox':18}
```

That gives classes 'wolf' weight 30 and 'fox' weight '18'